# C# WeakReference as Values in IDictionary, for ViewModel Cache in WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, weak-references

I'd like to validate my assumption.

So I have a class called say ViewModelProvider.

ViewModelProvider is a singleton and has a

```
IDictionary<string, WeakReference<ViewModelType>>
```

ViewModelType implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Basically the ViewModelProvider simply creates ViewModelType instances, and hands them out, if there already exists one it will hand the same instance.

Consumers of these ViewModelType instances just displays them by binding it like so:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding VMInstance}" />
```

The views are instantiated using typed DataTemplates.

With all that out of the way.

When a ViewModel is databound it's instance is referenced implicitly by the WPF framework subscribing to the PropertyChanged handler from INotifyPropertyChanged.

During this time if my understanding is correct the ViewModelType's instance is held by both the WeakReference and also by the WPF Binding. Is this correct?

When the view is unloaded or destroyed, resulting the PropertyChanged event handler from being unsubscribed, ViewModelType's instance is now ONLY held by WeakReference, meaning it can be collected at any point in time now by the GC, is this correct as well?

Everytime someone asks for a specific key'd ViewModelType, I will have to check if the WeakReference's referenced instance is collected or not, before re-initialising and handing it back, is this correct?

Also does anyone see any issues with this way of having a view model cache mechanism in place.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you use any DI container in your app? Why you dont want to pass this job about storing references and instantiating to DI container? What if you have to create several different views for same VM? What if you will want to get several instances of VM for same type?